# How to achieve consistent blur behavior with IE10 and webshims number input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-10, webshim

This sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marm/9y3HA/) displays 3 number inputs, each with blur and focus events assigned:

```
<script>

  jQuery('.number')
    .on('focus', function (e) {
      jQuery(e.currentTarget).val(1);
    })
    .on('blur', function (e) {
      jQuery(e.currentTarget).val(0);
    });

</script>

<input type='number' class='number' id='n0' min='0' max='1' autofocus />
<input type='number' class='number' id='n1' min='0' max='1' />
<input type='number' class='number' id='n2' min='0' max='1' />
```

Normally, under Chrome for example, focus sets input values to 1 and blur sets input values to 0. With IE10 and webshims however, values appear to be set on every other blur.

Should the blur event be handled differently?

Comment: This bug is fixed with now starting with version 1.12.6.

Comment: You are quick! Fix is confirmed - jsfiddle behaves correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you found a bug. Will fix this soon. As for now you can workaround this bug by using a setTimeout with a delay of 9.

http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/9y3HA/8/

```
setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery(e.currentTarget).val(0);
}, 9);
```